# Which data model to use to represent nested categories in a small SQL database?

Tags: sql, database, data-structures, treeview, hierarchical-data

I am writing a small web site for work where employees can consult video capsules on how to use the different programs that we use.  I was asked to organize the videos by categories and the categories need to be arbitrarily nested.

I've been looking into two ways to model this: nested sets and adjacency lists.  They both seem to have their ups and downs, and I was wondering if somebody could help me choose the model that would best fit my usage scenario.

- I want to display the categories in a menu along with the number of videos under that category
- The site will be updated once a week, if that.  The majority of the database activity is going to be reading.
- The site will not be heavily visited.  Never more than 2-3 users at once I'd expect.
- Categories are likely going to be established when we build the site and rarely (if ever) touched afterwards.  Maybe some categories will be added, but I don't expected categories to be deleted or moved around in the tree.
- This is a summer job, so I expect that somebody else will maintain the site after I'm gone.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: For what database?  Some have recursive/hierarchical query support, while others (MySQL) do not -- this can impact design.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a small lightly used database that's unlikely to see a lot of change....I wouldn't sweat the issue. Don't spend a lot of time thinking on it: just do it in the simplest, most straightforward, easiest to understand/implement manner.

Git'er done, as they say.

Comment: [I would agree with @Nicholas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Since reading is your main activity, answer would also depend upon where would you be accessing this from - SQL stored proc or .NET/C# library? BTW: do spend some time exploring options, an incorrect design will impact performance drastically - specially in hierarchical data.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser: I'm using PHP and MySQL.  As for exploring options, that's what I've been doing; Since the size of the database is small, and likely to remain small, I would definitely consider doing things naively (i.e. loading everything in RAM and using PHP to arrange the data) at the cost of decreased performance because it wouldn't be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

```
category
--------
category_id
name

category_nesting
----------------
parent_category_id
child_category_id

video
-------
video_id
more_stuff

video_category
--------------
video_id
category_id
```